# Classification of automorphism groups of groups of order $p^4$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

For the purpose of classifying another algebraic structure which is parametrised by the choice of a group and of an automorphism I need the classification up to isomorphism of automorphism groups of p-groups of order $p^4$.
I duly searched the web for a while and all the group theory manuals I could lay my hands on but I didn't find anything, not a hint.
Could someone provide a reference?
A good reference for the classification of groups of order $p^4$ would be useful too, since I found the following thesis [On p-groups of low power order](http://www.math.kth.se/~boij/kandexjobbVT11/Material/pgroups.pdf) but a different reference to help me confront the possible approaches to the problem would be of great help!

Comment: I would guess that the automorphism groups of groups of order $p^4$ have not been calculated before. So you will have to do it yourself!

Comment: This sounds both as good news and bad news for my thesis!

Comment: I'll try to upgrade the question to Mathoverflow, but if professor Holt says so I'm afraid that the matter is settled...

Answer (score 1):

For the classification of order $p^4$, you can find in Group Theory II, chapter 4 section 4, by M. Suzuki. Sorry I can not find classification of their automorphism groups.